# Query Error PHP select from where clause

Tags: php, mysql

Im try to get datatable from query, which select from where clause, but not working :

```
<?php
  include "koneksi.php";
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS urutan,t.      id_data, nama_aut, judul_abs, file_abs, status_lolos, status_bayar
  FROM datauser   WHERE status_lolos = "Sudah" t,
  (SELECT @rownum := 0) r");
   $data = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $data[] = $r;
}

 $i=0;
   foreach ($data as $key) {
    // add new button
   .....
$i++;
 }
   $datax = array('data' => $data);
echo json_encode($datax);
?>
```

error

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected 'Sudah' (T_STRING)

But if not use where clause , thats working fine :

```
  <?php
  include "koneksi.php";
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS urutan,t.       id_data, nama_aut, judul_abs, file_abs, status_lolos, status_bayar
  FROM datauser   t, 
  (SELECT @rownum := 0) r");
   $data = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $data[] = $r;
}
 ...
```

Anyone can help, im newbie..

Comment: Change `WHERE status_lolos = "Sudah"` to `WHERE status_lolos = 'Sudah'` or `WHERE status_lolos = \"Sudah\"`.

Comment: Look at the color highlighting. Also update from `mysql_` to `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: when i use 'Sudah' or \"Sudah\" that giving error ''<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given...

Comment: That means the query failed, use error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php (also note the big warning on this page)

Comment: REPLACE WHERE status_lolos = "Sudah" t WITH WHERE status_lolos = 'Sudah'

Comment: Because you're not checking to see if your query is successful. You should do `if ( ! $query = mysql_query(...) ) { echo mysql_error(); }` and it will give you the error.

Comment: when i try WHERE status_lolos = "Sudah" to WHERE status_lolos = 'Sudah', that not working..

Comment: plz remove t after 'Sudah' and place it after datauser

Comment: plz check query in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use double qoute for Sudah:

```
 FROM datauser   WHERE status_lolos = "Sudah" t,
```

Answer (score 0):

$query=mysql_query("SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS urutan,t.id_data, nama_aut, judul_abs, file_abs, status_lolos, status_bayar FROM datauser t  WHERE status_lolos = 'Sudah', (SELECT @rownum := 0) r");